# return index of array from return value of a method

Tags: java, oop

I have this method in one of my classes:

```
public int[] getCurrentGridPosition()
{        
    return new int[]{currentGridPosX, currentGridPosY};
}
```

Does Java allow something in the likes of:

```
int x, y;
x = getCurrentGridPosition()[0];
y = getCurrentGridPosition()[1];
```

If yes, how? If no, why?

Comment: Have you... tried it?

Comment: yes ... but you will create two array (one per call). `int[] coord = getCurrentPosition()` prevent this. Now this would have been quite simple to check.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Return an index? Return an array and access it via index?

Comment: Obviously - if you call a function twice, it is run twice......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does Java allow something in the likes of:

Yes, there is nothing<sup>*†*</sup> wrong with this piece of code. Here a full program with your code to prove it works:

```
class Main{
  private int currentGridPosX = 5, 
              currentGridPosY = 10;

  public static void main(String[] a){
    Main m = new Main();
    m.test();
  }

  private void test(){
    int x, y;
    x = getCurrentGridPosition()[0];
    y = getCurrentGridPosition()[1];
    System.out.print("x: "+x+"; y: "+y);
  }

  public int[] getCurrentGridPosition()
  {        
    return new int[]{currentGridPosX, currentGridPosY};
  }
}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##fZBBi8IwEIXv/RVDTxW7RQ97sXjy4GlhwYsiHrJtkKk2XZJpbSj97XWauFCFNZdkyDfvvZlCNOKjyC/DkF2FMfAlUHUBwK/GRpAEVARZrbVUtNWYf1dmD2v4jIGZ6XlmDswsF2kwCtU/V8zAkCC@mgpzKNkj2pFGdT6eQMw6pzU6Q8mNSt5cEc1S91EmJA35qg8m2ZyY//MSY9g2Buv7WtY6S9o8JUPCipWPi5OH7Dto@YB21pAsk6qmhL0VRWG7gnDezsMU7Piyk3B@XqZ4tv@Umev@NucctKRaKze66@xedh6/Lrj3hv0w3AE)

<sup>*†*: Compile/runtime wise there is nothing wrong. In terms of best practice there are of course things to improve.</sup>

> If yes, how?

`x = getCurrentGridPosition()[0];` will call the method and give an array as result, and will then get the element at index `0`, saving it in the field `x`.
`y = getCurrentGridPosition()[1];` will call the method again for a second time and give an array as result, and will then get the element at index `1`, saving it in the field `y`.

So in almost all cases it's best to only call the method once and save the result-array in a variable, and only then access its elements at the indices `0` and `1`:

```
int[] gridPositions = getCurrentGridPosition(); // The method is only called once now
int x = gridPositions[0],
    y = gridPositions[1];
System.out.print("x: "+x+"; y: "+y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it with some more lines of code?
For example, you can access the returned array like this:

```
int x, y;
int[] myArray = getCurrentGridPosition();
x = myArray[0];
y = myArray[1];
System.out.println("x: " + String.valueOf(x) + ", y: " + String.valueOf(y));
```